# How to add background color to text in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, adobe-fireworks

What's the easiest way to do it? I know CSS could just set background color of text very easily. And fireworks was able to do that. But I can't make it work now. I know there is a harder way: putting a rectangle below the text. Or putting the text inside the rectangle.

Comment: Are you asking simply how to change the color of text in Photoshop?

Comment: :) I'm asking about changing the background color, not text color. It could be think of as the fill color of the invisible textbox containing the text.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no text box colour in Photoshop. The only way is to draw rectangular shape layer below the text layer (you could also use a bitmap layer).

[image]

Yep, that's different to some other design software.

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to:

1. make a layer behind
2. make a rectangular selection and fill it with color

## or...

use a thick stroke XD

Comment: For the stroke, simply right-click the text layer and select `Blending Options...`. Then activate `Stroke`, select it, set the `Size` to 10, set the `Position` to `Outside` and change the `Color`, because black on black doesn't look so good! ;D